# Gitlab Docker Instance Startup Permission Denied secrets_helper.rb

Tags: docker, nas, portainer, rancheros

I'm trying to run the `gitlab-ce` docker image and am having issues with permission being denied for `secrets_helper.rb`. The following is pulled from the startup logs:

```
================================================================================
Recipe Compile Error in /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/gitlab/recipes/default.rb
================================================================================

Errno::EPERM
------------
Operation not permitted @ rb_file_chmod - /etc/gitlab/gitlab-secrets.json

Cookbook Trace:
---------------
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/package/libraries/helpers/secrets_helper.rb:121:in `chmod'
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/package/libraries/helpers/secrets_helper.rb:121:in `block in write_to_gitlab_secrets'
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/package/libraries/helpers/secrets_helper.rb:119:in `open'
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/package/libraries/helpers/secrets_helper.rb:119:in `write_to_gitlab_secrets'
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/package/libraries/helpers/settings_helper.rb:163:in `generate_secrets'
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/package/libraries/helpers/settings_helper.rb:167:in `generate_config'
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/gitlab/recipes/config.rb:26:in `from_file'
  /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/gitlab/recipes/default.rb:26:in `from_file'

Relevant File Content:
----------------------
/opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/package/libraries/helpers/secrets_helper.rb:

There was an error running gitlab-ctl reconfigure:

Operation not permitted @ rb_file_chmod - /etc/gitlab/gitlab-secrets.json

114:  
115:    def self.write_to_gitlab_secrets
116:      secret_tokens = gather_gitlab_secrets
117:  
118:      if File.directory?('/etc/gitlab')
119:        File.open('/etc/gitlab/gitlab-secrets.json', 'w', 0600) do |f|
120:          f.puts(Chef::JSONCompat.to_json_pretty(secret_tokens))
121>>         f.chmod(0600)
122:        end
123:      end
124:  
125:      nil
126:    end
127:  end
128:
```

I've created the container with the following:

```
docker run --detach \
  --hostname domain.name.com \
  --publish 4443:443 \
  --publish 4080:80 \
  --publish 4022:22 \
  --name gitlab \
  --restart always \
  --volume /mnt/nfs-1/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab \
  --volume /mnt/nfs-1/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab \
  --volume /mnt/nfs-1/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab \
  gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest
```

Permissions look like the following:

`/mnt`
[image: Rancher /mnt]

`/mnt/nfs-1`

```
drwxrwx---    5 1020     1020             5 Jun  2 23:13 gitlab
```

`/mnt/nfs-1/gitlab`

```
drwxrwx---    2 1020     1020            10 Jun  2 23:15 config
drwxrwx---    2 1020     1020             2 Jun  2 23:13 data
drwxrwx---    4 1020     1020             4 Jun  2 23:15 logs
```

The `/mnt/nfs-1` is an NFS share that's setup with rancher's config.

```
# /var/lib/rancher/conf/cloud-config.d/nfs.yml

rancher:
  services:
    nfs:
      image: walkerk1980/rancher-nfs-client
      labels:
        io.rancher.os.after: console, preload-user-images
        io.rancher.os.scope: system
      net: host
      privileged: true
      restart: always
      volumes:
      - /usr/bin/iptables:/sbin/iptables:ro
      - /mnt/nfs-1:/mnt/nfs-1:shared
      environment:
        SERVER: nas.stark.local
        SHARE: /mnt/pool/data_set
        MOUNT_OPTIONS: rw,noatime,nolock,soft,_netdev,auto
```

The **NFS** file share (in FreeNAS) looks like this:

[image: FreeNAS Permissions NFS]

However, the solution there didn't work for me and I'm not quite sure where the `git` user exists. I'd assume that it exists in the running image.

I also tried to downgrade/upgrade/different versions/ee edition with the same problem so I'm under the assumption it has something to do with the volumes?

External Resources

- [gitlab's issue tracker](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/63484)
- [Chown Problems NFSv3](https://www.reddit.com/r/docker/comments/e281ze/trying_to_mount_nfs_chmod_not_permitted/)
- [Chown Problems Windows => Unix Permissions](https://www.truenas.com/community/threads/nfs-permission-issues.22848/)
- [The Laymans Guide to RancherOS](https://www.truenas.com/community/threads/the-laymans-guide-to-rancheros-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-switch-to-docker.74324/)

Comment: The nfs folders on server should have the permissions allowing read/write to whenever user the container is using.

Comment: @HectorVido do you happen to know what those would look like? I'll also include the file permissions here.

Comment: If this folders on `/mnt` come from a nfs **server**, you need to fix permissions on nfs **server**. To see exactly what permissions you need, just remove this volumes, use a "docker managed one" like `--volume gitlab_config:/etc/gitlab`, access the container and list the files.

Comment: That makes sense. I'll add the rancher config file here too which is whats setting up the nfs file share. And look into updating the permissions for that. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Just added the NFS file share (hosted in FreeNas) too. However, whats weird here is that it seems like its writable.

Comment: :/ sorry, don't know how to solve.

Comment: Its okay, really appreciate the help! And it put me in a new direction too. Thanks again!

Comment: For anyone that might stumble upon this. I bypassed the issue entirely by not using the nfs share. I don't know how to get this to work when the calling application whats to change file permissions & owner on the nfs.